# How to use animation with transform CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image and want to move it to the right and then to left animation using CSS. However, I wanted to combine the drive with transform: scaleX (-1); as below:

----image--->            move to right

move to left with transform: scaleX (-1)
                       <------image----

I have the code:

```
 <div class="logo">
     <img  src="resources/images/logo.png" alt=""/> 
  </div> 

.logo{
-webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-delay: 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite ;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name: example;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-delay: 1s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;     
animation-timing-function: linear;}

@-webkit-keyframes example {
from {
    margin-left:  -200px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
to {
    margin-left: 200px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);      
}}

@keyframes example {    
 from {
    margin-left:  -200px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
to {
    margin-left: 200px;       
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}}
```

Comment: Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/bn42wkv7/
But I want to flip the image exactly when she gets 200px.

Comment: in fiddle why have you added `margin-left:-210px` in logo class?

Comment: I suspect you would need two animations for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get this effect with an alternated animation, because the *back* movement is different from the *forward* movement.

First, we need to set a single animation for both directions; then , you can add keyframes to control the reversal

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: coral;
  animation: custom 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes custom {    
   0% {
       margin-left:  -200px;
       transform: scaleX(1);
   }
   49% {
       margin-left: 200px;       
       transform: scaleX(1);
   }
   50% {
       margin-left: 200px;       
       transform: scaleX(-1);
   }
   100% {
       margin-left: -200px;       
       transform: scaleX(-1);
   }
}
```

```html
<div>TEST</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I wanted.
I was on the right track.
Thank you all